# Restarted activity can not get status of service it started before restart

Tags: android

Here is a situation, 
I have an android activity which starts a service (The service is meant to send/receive files etc). The service sendMessage() to the Activity via the handler created in Activity class object.
The Activity then shows the status of current action(s) service is performing on the views it contains.

Here is the problem

1. Activity starts
2. Activity created Handler in a global object
3. Activity starts the service -
4. User through the activity commands the service to begin the process of send/receive files
5. The service is now busy and also sending messages to UI through the handler obtained via the global object
6. The Activity receives and handleMessage() and publish the state on UI
7. The user now sends my Activity to background (may be he starts using another app)
8. During this process android probably kills my Activity but service is busy/running
9. Service in the mean time finishes
10. After some time the user opens the Activity,
11. (The problem) The Activity starts onCreate is called the activity does not know the last status of the service. whether it finished successfully or with failure or any other status last status..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences, SQLite, text files or simply static variable or variable/field of Application instance (implement singleton of Application to getInstance in any place of your code). Static variable and application instance will lose states in memory once killed by android.

Comment: can you please make it a bit more clear ? Do you mean if Activity is killed a static variable will still exist ? and on restart I can get value from there ?

Comment: Activity is part of Application (kind of). So, static variable is available while process is alive. When process is alive, Application is still alive too, so you can redefine class name of Application to have own `class ??? extends Application` to access to static or fields using singleton.

Comment: fine, and how about creating a static var in service class to store last status, is that not the same ?

Comment: hm, you can do that too, all static variables would be available. But if user really left your application, Android can decide to kill the process, so you potentially can lose even static variable. It really depends on logic of the application. If the result of service makes sense only for application life-time, than static, otherwise use files or sharedpreferences or other storages.

Comment: Yes I got you, if whole app is gone then It does not matter in my case, So I would just create a static var in service to store last status. I am not sure about Application class how it functions I will take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the way you started the service, how you should proceed.

Assuming the simpleste situation, service running in the same process and in mode `START_STICKY`,  the service remains in memory until you call `stopService()` from activity.

In this case, you can create a class level static variable that stores the service current status (i.e. not started, running, error, finished, etc.), and test it from your activity.

Regards.

Comment: a static var in the service class ?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I'm using it to control service status in my apps.